# Sql Query to breakdown

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following table structure in SQL Server

**Transaction**:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 **ID | FromEmployeeID | ToEmployeeID | OutgoingTotal | IncomingTotal**|
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1  |      10        |     20       |       10      |       50
   2  |      11        |     10       |       20      |       40
```

I need to transform this data in another table `Summary` by `employeeID`, as if a transaction started from an employee to an employee I have to enlist in summary as two records for each of employee (1 for from outgoing and one for incoming)

**Summary**:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 **ID | EmployeeID | outgoingcount| incomingcount | OutgoingTotal| IncomingTotal**|
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1  |      10    |     1        |       1       |   10         |  50
   2  |      20    |     0        |       1       |   0          |  50
   3  |      11    |     1        |       0       |   0          |  40
```

I also have the employee table in which employee id and other information of employee is there.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: There is some mismatch when you sum OutgoingTotal and IncomingTotal in both the tables. Is the data valid?

Comment: As per my understanding OutgoingTotal represents the calls(or whatever transaction it is) from FromEmployeeID  to ToEmployeeID and IncomingTotal is calls from ToEmployeeID to FromEmployeeID, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a temporary table and first insert your employee ids, then update the counts and sums in a separate query. Haven't tested this, but you can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Summary (
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  EmployeeID INT NOT NULL,
  OutgoingCount INT NOT NULL,
  IncomingCount INT NOT NULL,
  OutgoingTotal INT NOT NULL,
  IncomingTotal INT NOT NULL
)

--Get all the distinct 'from' employee IDs
INSERT INTO #Summary( EmployeeID )
SELECT DISTINCT FromEmployeeID FROM Transaction;

--Get the rest of the employee ids, except for those that have already been added to the table
INSERT INTO #Summary( EmployeeID )
SELECT DISTINCT ToEmployeeID FROM Transaction t
LEFT JOIN #Summary s ON s.EmployeeID = t.ToEmployeeID
WHERE s.EmployeeID IS NULL

--Update the summary table with the outgoing results
UPDATE s
SET OutgoingCount = e.OutgoingCount,
    OutgoingTotal = e.OutgoingTotal
FROM
  #Summary s
  JOIN (SELECT FromEmployeeID AS EmployeeID, COUNT(OutgoingTotal) AS OutgoingCount, SUM(OutgoingTotal) AS OutgoingTotal FROM Transaction t WHERE t.FromEmployeeID = s.EmployeeID GROUP BY t.FromEmployeeID) e ON e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID

--Repeat the process for incoming results
UPDATE s
SET IncomingCount = e.IncomingCount,
    IncomingTotal = e.IncomingTotal
FROM
  #Summary s
  JOIN (SELECT ToEmployeeID AS EmployeeID, COUNT(IncomingTotal) AS IncomingCount, SUM(IncomingTotal) AS IncomingTotal FROM Transaction t WHERE t.ToEmployeeID = s.EmployeeID GROUP BY t.ToEmployeeID) e ON e.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID

--End the end, select your results
SELECT
  *
FROM
  #Summary
```

Answer (score 0):

AS @Nithin says, the totals don't sum up in your example.

```
WITH AllEmployees AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId
    FROM [Transaction]
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES (FromEmployeeID)
              ,(ToEmployeeID)
    ) AS T(EmployeeId)
)
SELECT EmployeeId
      ,Outgoing.Records AS outgoingcount
      ,Incoming.Records AS incomingcount 
      ,COALESCE(Outgoing.Total, 0) AS OutgoingTotal
      ,COALESCE(Incoming.Total, 0) AS IncomingTotal
FROM AllEmployees
     CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT COUNT(1) AS Records
                ,SUM(OutgoingTotal) As Total
          FROM [Transaction]
          WHERE [Transaction].FromEmployeeID = AllEmployees.EmployeeId
     ) AS Outgoing
     CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT COUNT(1) AS Records
                ,SUM(IncomingTotal) AS Total
          FROM [Transaction]
          WHERE [Transaction].ToEmployeeID = AllEmployees.EmployeeId
     ) AS Incoming
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a query as per my understanding:

```
SELECT ISNULL(OutGoing.FromEmployeeID,Incoming.ToEmployeeID) EmployeeID,
       ISNULL(OutgoingCount,0) OutgoingCount,
       ISNULL(IncomingCount,0) IncomingCount,
       ISNULL(OutgoingTotal,0) OutgoingTotal,
       ISNULL(IncomingTotal,0) IncomingTotal
FROM (
        SELECT FromEmployeeID,
               COUNT(*) OutgoingCount,
               SUM(OutgoingTotal) OutgoingTotal
        FROM CallLogs
        GROUP BY FromEmployeeID
      ) OutGoing
FULL OUTER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT ToEmployeeID,
               COUNT(*) IncomingCount ,
               SUM(IncomingTotal) IncomingTotal
        FROM CallLogs
        GROUP BY ToEmployeeID
      ) Incoming
ON OutGoing.FromEmployeeID = Incoming.ToEmployeeID
```